# spring integration modify error message payload

Tags: spring-integration

For error handling in my spring integration flow I want to catch exceptions in a service activator which receives its input from a aggregator so its working on a collection of messages. When the exception is thrown though the full collection is sent as the message payload. Instead I want to put the actual item that threw the exception as the content of the error message.

```
public Collection<File> move(Collection<File> files){
    ...
    //process all files
    for(File file : files){         
        if(file.getName().equals("file-2.done")){
            throw new RuntimeException("SOMETHING WENT WRONG");
        }

        ... process the file
    }
```

My exception handler expects to retrieve the file that causes the error

```
File file = (File) message.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload();
```

but in this case a collection is send as the payload not a single file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework doesn't know what happens inside your `move` method.

You could do something like...

```
public classs MyFileFailureException extends RuntimeException {
    private final File file;
    public MyFileFailureException(String msg, File file) {
        super(msg);
        this.file = file;
    }
    public File getFailedFile() {return this.file}
}
```

Then in move()...

```
throw new MyFileFailureException("message", file);
```

Then, access it with...

```
message.getPayload().getCause().getFailedFile().
```

Comment: okay that makes sense but in this case the collection will be passed in by the framework and then ill additionally be specifying the failed file and retrieving that in the exception handler. Is that the idea? basically it sounds like we cant modify the payload of the exception message but can add more to it.

Comment: Correct; but it's not an overhead; the object (collection) already exists; the `ErrorMessage` just gets a reference to it.